# C: False condition is interpreted as true in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, false-positive

So I have the following program:

```
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp; 

int main() {
int i, j, temp;
i = 5;
j = 10;
temp = 0;
if (i > j)
    swap(i, j);
printf("%d %d %d", i, j, temp);
}
```

**This results in:**

```
10, 0, 0
```

What I don't understand is why the `if (5 > 10)` condition was executed as "true" even though 5 is not bigger than 10.

Comment: The result 10, 0, 0 should give you a hint it is not about the condition evaluating to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should teach you to avoid macros if at all possible and *always*, **always** use braces in control flow statements.

After macro expansion, your code will read:

```
if (i > j)
    temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
```

See the problem?

Comment: I did not know how macros worked that's why it was confusing to me, I thought it was called like a function but instead it's being replaced at the time of compilation and since there are no braces only the first statement "temp = i" falls inside the if statement, makes sense, thank you !

Comment: @EricBergman: This aspect of macros gives rise to a whole host of  pitfalls. Classic examples: `#define add(x, y) x + y` (try `add(1, 2) * 3`) and multiple evaluation of arguments. This is why in production macros you see everything wrapped to death inside parens and braces.

Comment: In your experience, is there really a point to using macros? If you can make a normal function why ever use macros? I see you mentioned "production macros" so it sounds like it's something that is widely use for some specific purpose.

Comment: @EricBergman: There are cases where not using macros can be very tedious. One of the most notable is that macros are agnostic to the types of their arguments, while functions are not (and C has no overloading to help there). I don't feel comfortable making a case *for* macros because I 'm not battle-tested in C. OTOH it's true that the less you know, the more you abuse them. Just keep the option in your head but put it at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 3):

This is because at the time of compilation `swap(i, j);` is being replaced by `temp=a; a=b; b=temp;`. Now the expanded macro looks like

```
 if(i > j)
    temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
```

At the time of execution only `temp = i` will not execute for `i > j` to be `false`.
If you wanna treat `swap(i, j)` like a function, then change your macro definition to

```
#define swap(a,b) do {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;} while (0)
```

Comment: Makes sense, this "trick" question was presented to me from a job interview but since I did not know how macros worked I got it wrong. I thought it was like a normal function call. Thank you.

Comment: @EricBergman; See the edit. Now your code will work as it should.